# Android Webview That Do Not open other browser after clicking login

Tags: android, webview

Im Creating a Simple webapp that Displays a Login Page of my Institution. The Page is Written in .aspx When i Click Login After Entering my Login Details , It Shows Me to use any Browser App to Open that Page, is There any Way to open the page in same app ??

public class portalview extends Activity {

```
private WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.portal);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://portal.saveetha.com/deptweb/home/Login.aspx");


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to implement  `WebViewClient()` and set like:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
@Override  
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
{  
  view.loadUrl(url);
  return true;
}  
}); 

webView.loadUrl("http://portal.saveetha.com/deptweb/home/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: Thanks !! Working Well :)

Comment: The Page has a Flash , How can I View That ??

Comment: @jana sorry i have no idea about flash.